# Concurrency in a rust tui app - lock starvation issue

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a tui app (built with the `tui-rs` crate) with its state inside a global `AppState` struct.

The app has 2 threads:

1. The main thread draws the contents to the screen in a loop. It needs an immutable reference to `AppState` to do the drawing.
2. A second thread occasionally spawns to do some cpu-heavy work. As a result it needs to update `AppState` and thus needs a mutable reference.

```
pub fn draw_screen() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut terminal = init_terminal().unwrap();

    // prepare app state
    let mut state = AppState::fresh_state();
    let arc_state = Arc::new(Mutex::new(state));

    loop {
        terminal.draw(|f| {
            // needs an immutable reference to AppState
            do_some_drawing(arc_state.clone());
        });

        // needs a mutable reference to AppState
        thread::spawn(|| {        
            do_some_calc(arc_state.clone());
        });
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Currently this results in a hanged app. The main thread keeps spinning in a loop, preventing the Mutex lock from ever being released. This means the second thread can never do its work. This in turn means the main thread (having checked whether the work is done yet) keeps spawning more worker threads, none of which can progress.

At least that's my best guess as to what's happening.

In case it matters, this is how I access the mutex in both immutable and mutable cases:

```
// when I need an immutable ref
let lock = thread_state.lock().unwrap();
let state = lock.deref();

// when I need a mutable ref
let mut lock = thread_state.lock().unwrap();
let state = lock.deref_mut();
```

What's the right way to resolve the above situation?

I've been reading about `RefCell` and channels but I'm not experienced enough to make a call. Would appreciate some guidance (any links to tutorials / docs super welcome).

Comment: Nit: the situation you describe is *not* a "deadlock".  Deadlocks arise when there are multiple threads **and** multiple locks, and two or more threads **each** hold some locks which they won't release until they acquire further locks from other such threads (resulting in a circular dependency, such that no thread can move forward).

Comment: Also, your code doesn't show multiple threads.  It shows a loop in a single thread, in which that single thread alternates between drawing and calculating?

Comment: Sorry, initially it didn't have the thread::spawn() because I greatly simplified the code before posting it here. I've added thread::spawn - this is how it looks in practice. I get your comment about deadlock, but I'm still not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Why do the calculation in a different thread though?  Until it completes, there's presumably nothing new to draw.

Comment: Because it takes a long time and freezes the drawing loop if it happens on the same thread. The order of operations I want: draw old state > kick off calc on new thread > keep drawing old state until done > draw new state